# nError in importing signals with createAffyIntensityFile (GWASTools)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am using the GWASTools package and I am facing an error to import my signal file. I tried to mimetize my real data set in the follow example:

```
library(GWASTools)
snp.anno <-   'snpID chromosome position      snpName
 AX-100676796          1   501997 AX-100676796
 AX-100120875          1   503822 AX-100120875
 AX-100067350          1   504790 AX-100067350'

snp.anno <- read.table(text=snp.anno, header=T)

 signals <-  'probeset_id    sample1.CEL  sample1.CEL   sample1.CEL
 AX-100676796-A   2126.7557   1184.8638  1134.2687
 AX-100676796-B   427.1864  2013.8512   1495.0654
 AX-100120875-A   1775.5816 2013.8512  651.1691
 AX-100120875-B    335.9226  2013.8512  1094.7429
 AX-100067350-A   2365.7755  2695.0053  2758.1739
AX-100067350-B    2515.4818   2518.2818  28181.289 '
 p1summ <- read.table(text=signals, header=T)                          
 write.table(p1summ, "del.txt", sep="\t", col.names=T, row.names=F, quote=F)
 p1summ <- createAffyIntensityFile("del.txt", snp.annotation=snp.anno)

Error: all(snp.annotation$snpID == sort(snp.annotation$snpID)) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) : coerced snpID to type integer
2: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) :
  coerced chromosome to type integer
```

I used the probe Names with 'A' and 'B' pattern also, the error was the same:

```
snp.annoab <-   'snpID chromosome position      snpName
 AX-100676796-A          1   501997 AX-100676796-A
AX-100676796-B          1   501997 AX-100676796-B
AX-100120875-A          1   503822 AX-100120875-A
AX-100120875-B          1   503822 AX-100120875-B
 AX-100067350-A          1   504790 AX-100067350-A
AX-100067350-B          1   504790 AX-100067350-B'

snp.annoab <- read.table(text=snp.annoab, header=T)

p1summ <- createAffyIntensityFile("del.txt", snp.annotation=snp.annoab)

Error: all(snp.annotation$snpID == sort(snp.annotation$snpID)) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) : coerced snpID to type integer
2: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) :
  coerced chromosome to type integer
```

In my real dataset the error is slight different, but do not work anyway:

```
Error: length(snp.annotation$snpID) == length(unique(snp.annotation$snpID)) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) : coerced snpID to type integer
3: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In .checkSnpAnnotation(snp.annotation) :
  coerced chromosome to type integer
```

And the strange thing is that:

```
> length(snp.annotation$snpID) == length(unique(snp.annotation$snpID))
[1] TRUE
```

Thus, seems that the error is not in agreement with the command (to check if  the length is the same). I am missing some important detail in the format of my inputs? I would be grateful for any help. Thank you!

Comment: If you ask on the [Bioconductor Support Site](https://support.bioconductor.org) and tag your question `GWASTools` you will likely get a prompt and authoritative answer.